# How to sum specific values in a csv file in Python?

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to search through a CSV file for certain criteria, and anything that fits that criteria, to be printed as a sum.

Example data:

```
|    city   |  state  |        college         |  cases |
|Huntsville | Alabama | Alabama A&M University |    42  |
```

etc, for hundreds of lines. I would like to be able to search the data, for example, the state of Alabama, and sum all cases that are equal to that state.

This is what I have so far:

```
category = input(What would you like to look up? Please enter 'city', 'state', or 'college': ")

if category == "city":
        city = input("Enter a city: ")
        for row in reader:
                if row[0] == city:
                        print("The city of", city, "has had a total of", row[3], "cases at", row[2])
                        print("All cities with the name", city, "have a total of", sum(row[3]), "cases.")
```

The row numbers entered correspond to the row I need in the original CSV file. All code works, except for my last line, where the sum command for the row clearly does not work. While playing around with different options, it does not like that it is a string variable (even though it's all numbers for the cases). Is there a better way to do this? Thank you.

Comment: It's a use case for `Pandas` (csv reading, find values, sum numbers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**sum(row[3])**, assuming it works at all, is just going to return **row[3]** (explanation [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_sum.asp)). You need to change your code as follows.

```
category = input(What would you like to look up? Please enter 'city', 'state', or 'college': ")

if category == "city":
    city = input("Enter a city: ")
    sum = 0
    for row in reader:
        if row[0] == city:
            print("The city of", city, "has had a total of", row[3], "cases at", row[2])
            sum += int(row[3])
    print("All cities with the name", city, "have a total of", sum, "cases.")
```

You won't know the total for the city until you have read all the rows for city.

Comment: when trying this, I get the error: 
"TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'str' " any thoughts?

Comment: Ooops yes fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting a data structure from csvreader that is either a list or a dictionary. I'll assume it's a list. The easy way is:

```
total = 0
for line in csvdata:
    if line[1] == 'Alabama':
         total += int(line[3])
```

that can be turned into a list comprehension form

```
total = sum([int(x[3]) for x in csvdata if x[1] == 'Alabama'])
```

(Update, thanks for the correction. Corrections.)

Comment: Crap what language are we writing today, Charles?

Comment: Hi Charlie, asked a Q a second ago but figured out my error. New issue: The summed number is only 0, no matter what the true sum is.

Comment: try replacing the `sum` with `print` and see what you're actually getting

Comment: If I had to guess, the value you're entering for which you're searching, or the value in the CSV, have some mystery characters like newline '\n' or space ' '. Then the == won't work.

Comment: @OlvinRoght Goddammit, I was certain I'd put that in